# Pendulum attached to a cart. What have I done wrong?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics

[image]

A bob of mass $m$ is attached to the base of a cart via a thread of length $l$. The cart is accelerating with a non-uniform acceleration with magnitude $a$. The positive x-direction is towards the right and the positive y-direction is downwards. A simple diagram of the situation is shown in the figure above. The problem which I am facing is that when I calculate the magnitude of tension $T$ in the thread using two different approaches, I get two different values. Please help me find the mistake in my solution.

**First approach (Observer is stationary)**

Assuming the magnitude of the displacement of the cart from its initial position to be $x_c$, the bob's $x$ and $y$ displacement from its initial position can be written as:
$x = x_c + l\sin\theta$
$y = l\cos\theta$

From Newton's laws, we will get:
$-T\sin\theta = m\ddot x = m\ddot x_c + ml(-\dot \theta^2\sin\theta + \ddot \theta\cos\theta)$
$mg - T\cos\theta = m\ddot y = ml(-\dot \theta^2\cos\theta - \ddot \theta\sin\theta)$

If we multiply the above equations by $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ respectively and add them up, we get the following equation:
$T = mg\cos\theta -ma\sin\theta + ml\dot \theta^2$

**Second approach (Observer is present in the cart)**
From the point of view of this observer, a pseudo force will act on the bob in the negative x-direction. From this reference frame, since there will be no displacement of the bob along the thread, from Newton's laws:
$T = mg\cos\theta - ma\sin\theta$

As you can see, we obtain two different values of $T$ using two different approaches. Please help me find out the mistake I am making.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first approach is correct.

For the second approach, You have not taken into account centripetal acceleration $m\omega^2l$ which is the term you are missing in your second equation.

Comment: @ahamshubham When you whirl a stone that's attached to a rope with your hand in the horizontal plane, the stone doesn't displace along the direction of the taut rope and yet we know that there's a net non-zero force (the tension of the rope) that's responsible for the centripetal acceleration experienced by the stone.

Comment: @user35508 Thank you for your answer. It clarifies everything.

Comment: @AjayMohan Thanks for your explanation but I think there is a displacement in the direction of the thread which leads to the centripetal acceleration and this acceleration is the quantity which I did not consider in my equation.

Comment: @ahamshubham Why do you say that? In the frame of the observer located in the cart, the mass $m$ doesn't experience a displacement along the direction of the thread since its velocity is perpendicular to the thread, right?  The centripetal acceleration is just resposible for changing the direction of the velocity of $m$.

Comment: @AjayMohan Oh, yeah. Makes perfect sense.